# Necessary and sufficient condition for constant function

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function.

If for any fixed $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $f_y(x_0,y)\equiv0$. And for any fixed $y_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $f_x(x,y_0)\equiv0$, then $f$ must be constant?

If $f$ is a polynomial, then $f$ must be constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be constant.

Hint: For any two points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, first move from $(x_1, y_1)$ to $(x_1, y_2)$, then to $(x_2, y_2)$.

(Or just apply Chain rule. Your conditions imply that $\nabla f$ is zero everywhere).